# Rolling 2 dice randomly (with URLs)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, random

I have this problem with rolling 2 dice, and then, if they match, the script should return which pair it was.

I have the dice pics on my server.

I must be doing some very simple things wrong but can't now figure out what the are.

Here is the URL of to this tasks page that I've made: http://rockworksstudio.fi/mamk/js/ot4/ot4b.html

And here is my current code on that page:

```js
var n1 = document.getElementsById("noppa1");
var n2 = document.getElementsById("noppa2");
var pari = document.getElementById("pari");
var pairs = ["Ykköset", "Kakkoset", "Kolmoset", "Neloset", "Vitoset", "Kutoset"];

function pelaa() {
  var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
  var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
  var url1 = "noppakuvat/noppa" + dice1 + ".jpg";
  var url2 = "noppakuvat/noppa" + dice2 + ".jpg";

  n1.src = url1;
  n2.src = url2;

  if dice1 == dice2 {
    pari.innerHTML = pairs.[dice1 - 1];
  } else pari.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button" onClick="pelaa()">Pelaa</button>
<p>
  <img src="noppakuvat/noppa1.jpg" id="noppa1" />
  <img src="noppakuvat/noppa1.jpg" id="noppa2" />
</p>

<p id="pari"></p>
```

Comment: getting a console error in the snippet I made for you `if dice1 == dice2 {` needs to be `if (dice1 == dice2) {` and then I get error for `pari.innerHTML = pairs.[dice1 - 1];` which should be without the dot. Also document.getElementsById needs to be singular

Comment: Typo: `getElementsById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: Thank You for your answer. About that latter error, how should I be doing this when I want to "get out" the nth element from my array (pairs).

Comment: Not sure I understand. The code I posted shows the text of the array if the dice are equal. What do you need it to show?

Comment: Hello and thank You both for your answers. I have corrected these errors (but not the pairs.[dice1 - 1] one) but even showing the correct (random) dice images doesn't work. Again here is my web page for this task, meaning that the code above (fixed) is there: http://rockworksstudio.fi/mamk/js/ot4/ot4b.html

Comment: If the URL is correct it does. Use the "inspect element" - each die has `<img src="noppakuvat/noppa1.jpg" id="noppa1">` or similar - You still have the error in your page: `pari.innerHTML = pairs.[dice1 - 1];` It has to be `pari.innerHTML = pairs[dice1 - 1];`

Comment: So my task is like this: "Make a sripct that shows two random dice images when button "Pelaa" is clicked. And IF the dice are the same then show which pair it was (ykköset, kakkoset, kolmoset, etc...).

Comment: IT WORKS NOW!!! HHHHHHHUGE THANK YOU ALL! :)

Comment: Great. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `if dice1 == dice2 {` needs to be `if (dice1 == dice2) {`
- `pari.innerHTML = pairs.[dice1 - 1];`  should be without the dot.
- document.getElementsById needs to be singular

Thanks Andrew Bone for the dice :)

```js
var n1 = document.getElementById("noppa1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("noppa2");
var pari = document.getElementById("pari");
var pairs = ["Ykköset", "Kakkoset", "Kolmoset", "Neloset", "Vitoset", "Kutoset"];

function pelaa() {
  var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
  var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6)) + 1;
  var url1 = "https://www.random.org/dice/dice" + dice1 + ".png";
  var url2 = "https://www.random.org/dice/dice" + dice2 + ".png";

  n1.src = url1;
  n2.src = url2;

  if (dice1 == dice2) {
    pari.innerHTML = pairs[dice1 - 1];
  } else {
    pari.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```css
https://www.random.org/dice/dice1
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button" onClick="pelaa()">Pelaa</button>
<p>
  <img src="https://www.random.org/dice/dice1.png" id="noppa1" />
  <img src="https://www.random.org/dice/dice1.png" id="noppa2" />
</p>

<p id="pari"></p>
```

Comment: such questions need to be closed as typo, does not help future users and are trivially solved by looking at the dev console.

Comment: I know. I however had written it already and I hate when someone takes the comments, post an answer and gets it accepted after I did the debugging. The question seems not to be over yet. He had more issues apparently

Comment: and thats why you need to vote to close, so nobody answers.

Comment: That takes a while. I can hammer duplicates but not hammer close - anyway I have voted to close - it is still open and now answered by someone else

Comment: I'm sorry. This is the first time for me @StackOverflow as far as I can remember, so I'm not too familiar with all the concepts. Please kindly advice me to properly close this.

Comment: It's ok. Too late to delete

Answer (score 1):

You got some syntax errors in your code.

**ERROR1**: Add parenthesis to if statment condition:

```
if dice1 == dice2 { // error 1, add parenthesis
```

should become:

```
if (dice1 == dice2) {
```

**ERROR2**: Remove the dot from the pairs array:

```
pari.innerHTML = pairs.[dice1 - 1]; // error 2, remove dot
```

should become:

```
pari.innerHTML = pairs[dice1 - 1];
```

**ERROR3**: There is no getElementsById function, but getElementById

```
var n1 = document.getElementsById("noppa1"); // error 3, change getElementsById to getElementById
var n2 = document.getElementsById("noppa2");
```

should become:

```
var n1 = document.getElementById("noppa1"); // error 3, change getElementsById to getElementById
var n2 = document.getElementById("noppa2");
```

Then you should have everything working as you want.

Comment: @mplungjan what exactly you mean, "go away"? I was typing the answer while you were typing yours. I do not see the point of your comment.

Comment: I have commented on all these 16 minutes ago and answered 8 minutes ago. If it took you that long to write then I apologise. It still should be closed

Comment: Actually, it took me about 5 minutes to debug and write this down. I didn't saw that there was an answer when I opened the question nor when I hit to post the answer. Yes, this should be closed by someone who can close it.

Comment: All the errors had been discussed in the first comment on the question. I decided to also post an answer since the close procedure takes so long answers show up identical to my comments. Anyway... :)

Comment: im voting down duplicate answers to a question that is already answered by the browser console, which already shows the syntax error. Syntax error questions and answers are not helpful in this forum, it is unlikely to help future readers, thats why there is a specific close reason for syntax error questions (which I voted for).

Comment: @Zig Mandel well, as I already commented above, we were writing answers at the same time.. You can check both answers post time. When I opened the question there was NO answers at all, nor any comments. I did not "steal" mplungjan answer. I spent 5 minutes to debug this and write down proper answer. So, your vote down seems pointless to me.

Comment: i actually tried to undo but so wont let me unless you edit

Comment: @ZigMandel ok, just edited my answer. Actually it had some grammar typos!